# Spring boot DI not working for scala typeclass

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot

Spring boot DI not working for scala typeclass. Throwing `NoSuchBeanException`. I am using spring 4.3.13 and spring boot version 1.5.9

This is pseudo code snippet for reference:

```
trait Repo[T]

@Repository
class RedisRepo @Autowired()(redis: RedisClient) extends Repo[Event]


class RedisDao @Autowired()(repo: Repo[Event])
```

I have also tried using `@Qualifier` for the constructor parameter in `RedisDao` class. However, its also not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, typeclasses is a different concept. Seems that you misuse this term.

Comment: I guess that Spring instantiates beans using runtime reflection and has no access to type parameters due to type erasure.
You could introduce an interface `IRedisRepo extends Repo[Event]` and `class RedisDao @Autowired()(repo: IRedisRepo)`

Comment: @simpadjo thanks for reply. Your solution wont work. So I have a method in Repo trait which takes parameter T, def addOrUpdate(event: T) : Boolean......now if I try to use that method inside RedisDao, for example repo.addOrUpdate(event)...it will show compile time error as repo is an interface in your case.

Comment: does it help making `trait IRedisRepo extends Repo[Event]` ?

Comment: My bad..its working... However, RedisDao is tightly coupled to IRedisRepo which is in turn tied to Repo[Event], what if i want to use Repo[Event1] type....in that case... I will have to change the code...is there any way I can use DI in that case too?

Comment: Yes, you have to adjust `IRedisRepo`s type parameter.